# Possible to convert only a single label in a shapefile to annotation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, labeling, annotation

In ArcMap 10.3, is there a way to convert only a single label in a shapefile to annotation? I have a shapefile of 41 points (labeled 1 to 41). I only have one label that needs to be moved slightly to clarify which point it is associated with and converting to annotation would then make it where I could not easily change the placement properties etc for the entire shapefile. So, was wondering if anyone knew a way to move only the one label?

Comment: Shapefiles cannot contain Annotation, maybe you mean the annotation in an mxd.

Comment: Converting the labels to annotation not the shapefiles. Just wanted to know if a single label could be converted as opposed to all labels associated with the shapefile

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert a single label to annotation, you need to start with just a single label! Use the [SQL query](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-using-label-classes-to-label-fea.htm) option to only show a label for a single feature, for example selecting by Object ID. Make sure all the other label classes are turned off, then [convert to annotation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/map/working-with-text/converting-labels-to-annotation.htm) in the usual way.

Answer (score -1):

After playing with the Labeling tool bar..."Use Maplex Label Engine" did the trick for that particular label.

Comment: This does not sound right to me.  Using Maplex vs Standard Label Engine might affect where a label and subsequent annotation is placed but not whether a single label can be converted into annotation.

Comment: @PolyGeo Using maplex moved that one particular label in a way that was satisfactory it obviously did not affect whether it could be converted to annotation. I would still be interested in doing that, but for that instance maplex was adequate. I should have been more clear in my earlier comment that maplex moved the label in a way that would do for the moment and that was all.